# VBA: Type mismatch error in For...If...Delete loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, type-mismatch

I'm creating a chart from VBA in Excel, which will be as its own sheet & not embedded in a sheet. As such, at the beginning of the script, I want to check to see if the sheet name already exists & if so, deletes it.

My code below throws a `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch` error at the For statement, but I can't see any reason why. Any ideas?

I'm using Excel in Office 365.

```
Sub CreateChart()
' Macro to create a chart based on a given cross section ID

Dim cht As Object
Dim xsID As Integer
Dim tabName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

xsID = Worksheets("INPUT").Range("D6")

tabName = "XS_" & CStr(xsID)
Debug.Print tabName

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Debug.Print ws
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If ws.Name = tabName Then
        ws.Delete
        Debug.Print "Sheet deleted."
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next ws
```

Comment: What line errors?

Comment: `Debug.Print ws` should be `Debug.Print ws.name` Not sure if that is your error, I get an object doesn't support property or method error 438 when I test.

Comment: As the sheet I'm trying to delete is a chart, I need to loop through all sheets, not only worksheets. Debug.Print is to track iterations in For loop, prints to console.

Comment: "I need to loop through all sheets" - not really. You need to loop through `Charts`. Unless there's a chance that a regular worksheet has the same name as the desired chart name. If that's the case, then `Dim ws As Chart` will still throw a type mismatch.